# in Xcode-4 when I "add expression" to the debug area it does work, and I get a little "E" to the left of expression?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

in Xcode-4 when I "add expression" to the debug area it does work, and I get a little "E" to the left of expression?

For example I have a breakpoint set and the debugger has run to this point.  I have a local variable named "tempCell" which has a little "L" to the left of it in the debugger view.  The information for this is right there OK, it's obviously one of the current variables in scope so XCode shows it to you.

When I go "Add Expression" and type in the same variable, "tempCell", then when it going at the bottom of the list there are no values show, it is slightly greyed out, and  I get a little "E" to the left of expression?

What does the "L" and "E" mean, and why doesn't it show me the value?

[also I guess it's a given that there is no intellisense when you're typing in the "add expression" box? - i.e. like there is in Microsoft Visual Studio]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the 'L' means it's a **L**ocal variable, and 'E' means it's an **E**xpression. As far as it being disabled as an expression (slightly greyed out), it may be because you didn't actually enter an expression but a simple variable.

Comment: thanks - but re the definition of "expression" does this mean one can't add something like "tempCell" (a variable) and see it's value?  Or how about "tempCell.contentView" for example?  Do you happen to know how flexible the "expression" area is meant to be?

Comment: @Greg: I'm not an XCode person, which is why I said I was guessing. I'd suspect, though, that you watch local variables like `tempCell` as local variables; expressions are typically more complex (like `a >= b`), meaning an expression that actually has to be evaluated to return a value.

Comment: you're probably right I guess - will wait for a bit to see if anyone else chimes in